# btrfs errors when running newer kernel

Tags: linux, filesystems, btrfs

There is a strange btrfs related problem I'm facing on a server. When running a kernel version up to 4.9, everything works like a charm. If I upgrade to any version >= 4.19, everything breaks down. The newer kernel logs these errors:

```
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:22 2023] BTRFS info (device dm-1): using crc32c (crc32c-intel) checksum algorithm
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:22 2023] BTRFS info (device dm-1): disk space caching is enabled
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:22 2023] BTRFS info (device dm-1): bdev /dev/mapper/vg0-root errs: wr 0, rd 4, flush 0, corrupt 0, gen 0
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:23 2023] BTRFS info (device dm-1): checking UUID tree
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:25 2023] BTRFS critical (device dm-1): corrupt leaf: root=5 block=7800258560 slot=0 ino=22544639, invalid inode transid: has 140710402240512 expect [0, 9501327]
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:25 2023] BTRFS error (device dm-1): read time tree block corruption detected on logical 7800258560 mirror 1
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:26 2023] BTRFS critical (device dm-1): corrupt leaf: root=5 block=86444384256 slot=1 ino=8651007, invalid inode transid: has 140710402240512 expect [0, 9501327]
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:26 2023] BTRFS error (device dm-1): read time tree block corruption detected on logical 86444384256 mirror 1
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:26 2023] BTRFS critical (device dm-1): corrupt leaf: root=5 block=86032809984 slot=41 ino=24641791, invalid inode transid: has 140710402240512 expect [0, 9501327]
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:26 2023] BTRFS error (device dm-1): read time tree block corruption detected on logical 86032809984 mirror 1
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:26 2023] BTRFS critical (device dm-1): corrupt leaf: root=5 block=8081629184 slot=0 ino=8651599, invalid inode transid: has 140710402240512 expect [0, 9501327]
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:26 2023] BTRFS error (device dm-1): read time tree block corruption detected on logical 8081629184 mirror 1
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:26 2023] BTRFS critical (device dm-1): corrupt leaf: root=5 block=86032809984 slot=41 ino=24641791, invalid inode transid: has 140710402240512 expect [0, 9501327]
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:26 2023] BTRFS error (device dm-1): read time tree block corruption detected on logical 86032809984 mirror 1
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:26 2023] BTRFS critical (device dm-1): corrupt leaf: root=5 block=7800258560 slot=0 ino=22544639, invalid inode transid: has 140710402240512 expect [0, 9501327]
[Fri Oct 27 23:44:26 2023] BTRFS error (device dm-1): read time tree block corruption detected on logical 7800258560 mirror 1
```

where with 4.9 all is well.

Same with `btrfs check` with kernel version >=5:

```
root@rescue ~ # btrfs check /dev/mapper/vg0-root 
Opening filesystem to check...
Checking filesystem on /dev/mapper/vg0-root
UUID: 18c05fd2-0569-420b-bb74-676b2327d3d5
[1/7] checking root items
[2/7] checking extents
[3/7] checking free space cache
[4/7] checking fs roots
root 5 inode 8651007 errors 100000, invalid inode generation or transid
root 5 inode 8651008 errors 100000, invalid inode generation or transid
root 5 inode 8651599 errors 100000, invalid inode generation or transid
root 5 inode 8651600 errors 100000, invalid inode generation or transid
root 5 inode 22544639 errors 100000, invalid inode generation or transid
root 5 inode 24641791 errors 100000, invalid inode generation or transid
root 5 inode 40419460 errors 200, dir isize wrong
root 5 inode 44021300 errors 200, dir isize wrong
ERROR: errors found in fs roots
found 187456020480 bytes used, error(s) found
total csum bytes: 179106780
total tree bytes: 2667675648
total fs tree bytes: 2107199488
total extent tree bytes: 305291264
btree space waste bytes: 643077002
file data blocks allocated: 496942690304
 referenced 175125786624
```

and the contents show in a decently garbled manner:

```
root@rescue ~ # ll /mnt/
ls: cannot access '/mnt/proc': Input/output error
ls: cannot access '/mnt/run': Input/output error
ls: cannot access '/mnt/sys': Input/output error
ls: cannot access '/mnt/etc': Input/output error
ls: cannot access '/mnt/lib64': Input/output error
ls: cannot access '/mnt/usr': Input/output error
total 32K
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.0K Oct 27 20:18 bin
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Sep 27  2014 boot
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Sep 27  2014 dev
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? etc
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   12 Dec 23  2014 home
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   31 Oct 26 11:04 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-26-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   30 Oct 26 17:24 initrd.img.old -> boot/initrd.img-4.9.0-13-amd64
-rw-r----- 1 root root  659 Sep 27  2014 installimage.conf
-rw-r----- 1 root root 9.8K Sep 27  2014 installimage.debug
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  420 Oct 26 17:22 lib
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? lib64
drwx------ 1 root root    0 Sep 12  2012 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   22 Sep 12  2012 media
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Apr  2  2019 mnt
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root   24 Dec 27  2019 opt
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? proc
drwx------ 1 root root  560 Oct 27 22:47 root
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? run
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3.1K Oct 27 20:18 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    0 Sep 12  2012 srv
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? sys
drwxrwxrwt 1 root root  106 Oct 27 23:35 tmp
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? usr
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  118 Sep 28  2014 var
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 Oct 26 11:04 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-26-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Oct 26 17:24 vmlinuz.old -> boot/vmlinuz-4.9.0-13-amd64
```

The moment I boot with kernel 4.9, these errors magically disappear and reads/writes work perfectly fine. Checked and rechecked, files are correctly read, written, reread and rewritten; just as long as I stay on version 4.9.

I have upgraded other servers using btrfs to newer versions with no problems, so it's not something generic. Any asistance, welcome.

Answer (score 0):

After lots of hours and searching, [this](https://lore.kernel.org/linux-btrfs/36d45e31-f125-4b21-a68e-428f807180f7@gmail.com/) thread helped me form the following path that worked (it *needs* console, don't try this with ssh):

- With kernel 4.9, get down to runlevel 1 and then create copies of the offending directories:

  - `rsync -acv /usr /usr_new`
  - `rsync -acv /etc /etc_new`
  - `rsync -acv /lib64 /lib64_new`
  - `rsync -d /proc /proc_new`
  - `rsync -d /run /run_new`
  - `rsync -d /sys /sys_new`

Boot using a USB or something with kernel 4.9 if possible, otherwise just stay in runlevel 1; then move out of the way the offending folders:

- `mkdir /t && mv /etc /lib64 /usr /proc /run /sys /t`

**At this moment if you have not booted with a USB the system will crash, because critical libraries will not be available.**

If the system crashed, boot from a USB or start some rescue system with either kernel 4.9 or newer version, it won't make a difference. Mount the partition under /mnt and proceed to rename all *_new folders to their appropriate names:

- `for i in etc lib64 usr proc run sys; do mv /mnt/${i}_new /mnt/$i; done`

When finished reboot the system with kernel 4.9 to verify it works. If all is well, remove the /t folder holding the old offending directories. Finally, reboot using the newer kernel. There should be no problem.

PS: The directories named above (/etc, /lib64, /usr, /proc, /run and /sys) are the ones that caused the BTRFS error on the system I was trying to upgrade, so don't just copy/paste irresponsibly.